# Firestore can we use more than one ARRAY_CONTAINS?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I am using Firestore with Node JS. 
Is there anyway to use ARRAY_CONTAINS more than once in the same query.

Answer (score 1):

No, the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#compound_queries) is clear about this limitation:

> You can only perform range comparisons (<, <=, >, >=) on a single
>   field, and **you can include at most one array_contains clause in a
>   compound query.**

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am aware of this limitation as I cannot use a WHERE clause with array-contains more than once, but is there away to make something like SQL like '%QUERY%'.

Comment: That's a whole different question, and no, there are no substring filters either.